# How i move an image from left to right in swift?

Tags: swift, animation, uiimageview

**I did that...**

[image: Screen Shot]

```
ivImageLoadingInside.center = CGPoint(x: 25, y: 0)
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {
   self.ivImageLoadingInside.center = CGPoint(x: 80, y: 0)
}, completion: nil)
```

But always stops in the middle.

**Here is the image with the animation**

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it! You have to put the constraints and do this...

if animate {
ivImageLoadingInside.frame = CGRect(x: 0 - 160, y: 123, width: 160, height: 12)

```
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.2, delay: 0, options: .repeat, animations: {
            self.ivImageLoadingInside.frame = CGRect(x: ScreenSize.SCREEN_WIDTH, y: 123, width: 160, height: 12)

        }, completion: nil)
    } else {
        ivImageLoadingInside.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    }*
```

Look at this link http://mathewsanders.com/prototyping-iOS-iPhone-iPad-animations-in-swift/

Answer (score 9):

```
private func animation(viewAnimation: UIView) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
        viewAnimation.frame.origin.x = +viewAnimation.frame.width
    }) { (_) in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, delay: 1, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {
            viewAnimation.frame.origin.x -= viewAnimation.frame.width
        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.ivImageLoadingInside.center = CGPoint(x: 80 - self.ivImageLoadingInside.bounds.width / 2, y: 0)
```